# Fast exponentiation: real^real (C++ MinGW, Code::Blocks)

Tags: c++, floating-point, exponentiation

I am writing an application where in a certain block I need to exponentiate reals around 3*500*500 times. When I use the exp(y*log(x)) algorithm, the program noticeably lags. It is significantly faster if I use another algorithm based on playing with data types, but that algorithm isn't very precise, although provides decent results for the simulation, and it's still not perfect in terms of speed.

Is there any precise exponentiation algorithm for real powers faster than exp(y*log(x))?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need good accuracy, and you don't know anything about the distribution of bases (x values) a priori, then pow(x, y) is the best portable answer (on many -- not all -- platforms, this will be faster than exp(y*log(x)), and is also better behaved numerically).  If you do know something about what ranges x and y can lie in, and with what distribution, that would be a big help for people trying to offer advice.

The usual way to do it faster while keeping good accuracy is to use a library routine designed to do many of these computations simultaneously for an array of x values and an array of y values.  The catch is that such library implementations tend to cost money (like Intel's MKL) or be platform-specific (vvpowf in the Accelerate.framework on OS X, for example).  I don't know much about MinGW, so someone else will need to tell you what's available there.  The GSL may have something along these lines.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your algorithm (in particular if you have few to no additions), sometimes you can get away with working (at least partially) in log-space.  You've probably already considered this, but if your intermediate representation is log_x and log_y then log(x^y) = exp(log_y) * log_x, which will be faster.   If you can even be selective about it, then obviously computing log(x^y) as y * log_x is even cheaper.  If you can avoid even just a few exponentiations, you may win a lot of performance.  If there's any way to rewrite whatever loops you have to get the exponentiation operations outside of the innermost loop, that's a fairly certain performance win.